# How to get error messages in a form from a separated php file

Tags: php, wordpress, forms

I'm working on a website in wordpress and there is a login form to a customer's own application in the header. I have included in the header file the form and it works perfectly. When the login and password  are entered the user are sent to the application without problems.

The problem is when there is some error in validadation. In this case the login is not completed and wordpress page just is loaded again.

How do I receive the error message in the Wordpress page and not reload the page?

Below the form that is in Wordpress

```
<form class="f1" method="post" action="http://path-to-application/login.php">
    <div><input title="Number with 6 digits" type="text" class="txt titulo num" name="titulo" placeholder=" Number with 6 digits "></div>
     <div><input title="Senha" type="password" class="txt senha num" name="senha" placeholder="Senha"></div>
     <div><input type="submit" class="enviar loader" name="acao" value="Entrar"><a href="#" class="form-rec-pswd">Esqueci a senha</a></div>
     <div class="form-alerta">
         <div class="form-alerta-header"><span>!</span></div>
         <div class="form-alerta-content"><?php if($_SESSION["alerta"] != null){ echo $_SESSION["alerta"]; } ?></div>
     </div>
</form>
```

In the login.php file the section that handles the error is below:

```
switch($autenticarAcesso[0]["IDERRO"])
    {
        case 101:    
            $_SESSION["alerta"] = "Message 1.";
            break;            
        case 106:    //Erro 106
            $_SESSION["alerta"] = "Message 2.";
            break;
        case 666:    
            $_SESSION["alerta"] = "Message 3.";
            break;            
        default:                
            $_SESSION["erro"] = $autenticarAcesso[0]["MSG_ERRO"];    
}
```

How can i get the message from $_SESSION["alerta"] in the form in wordpress?

Comment: You already stored the error in a session and printed it out in the html, why not just redirect back?

Answer (score 0):

You just need turn off value of `display_errors` on your file `php.ini`. (Or use error_reporting function on bootstrap application) ;)

Read about error_reporting:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php#refsect1-function.error-reporting-examples

And error_log:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php
- [Setting display_errors=0 and log_errors=1 without php.ini](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9729000/setting-display-errors-0-and-log-errors-1-without-php-ini)